# Unable to create schema/table from presto on top of AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, presto

I am trying to create schema from presto-cli on top of AWS S3.

**presto-setup** 
        version : 330
        single node with coordinator and worker.

**hive_s3.properties:** catalog details

> connector.name=hive-hadoop2
>   hive.metastore.uri = thrift://10.81.1.197:9083
>   hive.non-managed-table-writes-enabled = true
>   hive.s3.use-instance-credentials = false
>   hive.s3.aws-access-key = XXX
>   hive.s3.aws-secret-key = XXX 
>   hive.s3.endpoint = https://.s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com

When I tried to create a schema/table from presto cli, getting the following Error.

ERROR:

> create schema test1 with ( location = 's3a://bucket');
>   Query 20200302_054953_00004_7ep7a failed: Got exception: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException presto-test-mahesh: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS Credentials provided by SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider 
>   InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint .

Tried adding environment variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY but still, it is unable to identify credentials.

And also tried by adding following properties in core-site.xml
fs.s3a.access.key 
fs.s3a.secret.key

But still the same.

Comment: You should configure `hive.s3.aws-access-key` and `hive.s3.aws-secret-key`. See docs https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#amazon-s3-configuration

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen, should hive.s3.aws-access-key this be added in hive-site.xml ? I am facing the same error. I am able to connect to object storage from hive but presto it throws error

Comment: @Vidya hive.s3.aws-access-key and hive.s3.aws-secret-key should be added to hive.properties (not hive-site.xml). BTW updated docs link https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/hive-s3.html